# SQL join condition either A or B but not both A and B

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have sales data by years and quarters and for the last year I want to fill missing quarters with last available value.

Say we have source table:

```
+------+---------+-------+--------+
| year | quarter | sales | row_no |
+------+---------+-------+--------+
| 2018 |       1 |  4000 |      5 |
| 2018 |       2 |  6000 |      4 |
| 2018 |       3 |  5000 |      3 |
| 2018 |       4 |  3000 |      2 |
| 2019 |       1 |  8000 |      1 |
+------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Desired results:

```
+------+---------+-------+------------------------+
| year | quarter | sales |                        |
+------+---------+-------+------------------------+
| 2018 |       1 |  4000 |                        |
| 2018 |       2 |  6000 |                        |
| 2018 |       3 |  5000 |                        |
| 2018 |       4 |  3000 |                        |
| 2019 |       1 |  8000 |                        |
| 2019 |       2 |  8000 | <repeat the last value |
| 2019 |       3 |  8000 | <repeat the last value |
| 2019 |       4 |  8000 | <repeat the last value |
+------+---------+-------+------------------------+
```

So the task is to make Cartesian of year and quarter and left join to it the sales either corresponding or the last.

This code gets me almost there:

```
select r.year, k.quarter, t.sales
from (select distinct year        from [MyTable]) r cross join
     (select distinct quarter     from [MyTable]) k left join
     [MyTable] t
     on (r.year = t.year and k.quarter=t.quarter) or row_no=1
```

How to correct the last line (condition of join) so thet the 2018 is not doubled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses outer apply:

```
select y.year, q.quarter, t.sales
from (select distinct year from [MyTable]) y cross join
     (select distinct quarter from [MyTable]) q outer apply
     (select top (1) t.*
      from [MyTable] t
      where t.year < y.year or
            (t.year = y.year and t.quarter <= q.quarter)
      order by t.year desc, t.quarter desc
     ) t;
```

For your volume of data, this should be fine.

A more efficient method -- assuming you are only assigning values to the end -- would be:

```
select y.year, q.quarter,
       coalesce(t.sales, tdefault.sales)
from (select distinct year from [MyTable]) y cross join
     (select distinct quarter from [MyTable]) q left join
     [MyTable] t
     on t.year = y.year and
        t.quarter = q.quarter cross join
     (select top (1) t.*
      from [MyTable] t
      order by t.year desc, t.quarter desc
     ) tdefault
```

Answer (score 1):

A very different approach using a CTE and some window functions. This doesn't require 2 scans of the table, nor a triangular join.

```
WITH VTE AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (2018,1,4000,5),
                 (2018,2,6000,4),
                 (2018,3,5000,3),
                 (2018,4,3000,2),
                 (2019,1,8000,1)) V([Year],[Quarter],sales, row_no)),
CTE AS(
    SELECT Y.Year,
           Q.Quarter,
           V.sales,
           V.row_no,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN V.sales IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY Y.[Year], Q.[Quarter]
                                                                 ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Grp
    FROM (VALUES(2018),(2019)) Y([Year])
         CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)) Q([Quarter])
         LEFT JOIN VTE V ON Y.[Year] = V.[Year] AND Q.[Quarter] = V.[Quarter])
SELECT C.[Year],
       C.[Quarter],
       MAX(C.sales) OVER (PARTITION BY C.Grp) AS Sales
FROM CTE C;
```

This will only work on SQL Server 2012+ (as `ROWS BETWEEN` was introduced with SQL Server 2012), however, hopefully you're not using 2008- which are all (almost) entirely out of support.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply do `JOIN` :

```
SELECT TT.YEAR, TT.Quarter, COALESCE(T.SALES, MAX(T.SALES) OVER (PARTITION BY TT.YEAR)) AS sales 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T.YEAR, TT.Quarter
      FROM [MyTable] T CROSS JOIN
           ( SELECT DISTINCT TT.Quarter FROM [MyTable] TT ) TT
     ) TT LEFT JOIN 
     [MyTable] T 
     ON TT.YEAR = T.YEAR AND TT.Quarter = T.Quarter;
```

**EDIT :**  I just misread the question for additional `quarter`s so, you need `APPLY` in `OUTER` JOIN :

```
SELECT TT.YEAR, TT.Quarter, COALESCE(T.SALES, T1.SALES) AS Sales 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT T.YEAR, TT.Quarter
      FROM [MyTable] T CROSS JOIN
           ( SELECT DISTINCT TT.Quarter FROM [MyTable] TT ) TT
     ) TT LEFT JOIN 
     [MyTable] T 
     ON TT.YEAR = T.YEAR AND TT.Quarter = T.Quarter OUTER APPLY 
     ( SELECT TOP (1) T.*
       FROM [MyTable] T
       WHERE T.YEAR = TT.YEAR
       ORDER BY T.Quarter DESC
     ) T1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that the fact that Sales in last period is accidentally highest does not influence your query?

Comment: Say time passed, and we have additional quarter in source table. What if 2019 Q2 Sales=7000 (so less then 2019 Q1). Then MAX partition by year would produce 8000 (value for 2019 Q1) which is not what I want. I want last available value which in that case would be 2019 Q2.

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin. . .  Correct i misread the question forget the scenario that you had. Thank you.